# Continue scanning a string until it has found the first/last occurrence of a string

Tags: java, regex, string, computer-science

I have this line of text that I want to scan using regex.

```
axhaweacb
```

I want to get the text from "a" to "b". This is my current pattern:

```
pattern = "a.*?b";
```

The current output is: `axhaweacb` (it's taking everything in between a and b), but what I want to receive back is "acb".

Why you may ask? The logic/regex I am trying to apply is:
When you find the first occurrence of the "from" regex ("a"), start scanning. If you find another occurrence of the "from" letter without finding the "last" occurrence of a letter - in this case "b", remove the previous string - which is `axh` so that the string becomes: `aweacb`. If you find another occurrence of "from" - in this case `a`, without finding "to" - `b`. Remove the previous string so that it becomes `acb`. Then start scanning again. In this case we have found our pattern - a to b, without another "a" in our way.

I know that I can substring the string to begin with, and strip down everything until the last occurance of "a" - but I want to reuse this for different strings as well. And in that case, it will always substring everything until the last occurance of something - which results in removing a lot of data.

I hope I made my question/problem clear. If not, please tell me and I will do my best to clarify my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know that your string will always be 3 chars long? In that case it seems you could use the pattern `"a.b"`. I don’t know whether it can be generalized to your other strings, but you can give it a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex engine searches for a match from left to right. When it finds `a` with `a.*?b`, it is the first `a` in your string. Then, the first `b` found and matched  is the last character in your `axhaweacb` string.

**Lazy quantifier matches up to the closest right-most character matching the subsequent subpattern**, not the shortest possible substring.

So, what you need is a way to *exclude* (=fail if found) all occurrences of the leading *and* trailing subpatterns in between them.

It can be done with the help of a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
pattern = "a(?:(?!a|b).)*b";
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jE4qL5/1)

Comment: FYI, if you have newlines in your input, you need to also specify the DOTALL modifier so that `.` could match linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
a(?:(?![ab]).)*b
```

- `(?![ab])` is the negative regex to match anything but `a` and b`
- `(?:(?![ab]).)*` matches 0 or more of any character that is not `a` and b`, thus giving us shortest match between`a`and`b`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sH0xT2/2)

Comment: Thank you. It's working. However, how would I go about if I want to reuse this regex for different strings without having to change the regex everytime. For example, trying to match "my name is jack" with this regex: name(?:(?![namejack]).)*jack . This returns "name is jack". But when I try:
my(?:(?![myjack]).)*jack to match the whole string - it returns nothing. Any idea why?

Comment: Inside `[...]` you cannot use multi character strings. You can use: [`\bname\b(?:(?!\b(name|jack)\b).)*\bjack\b`](https://regex101.com/r/sH0xT2/3)